# Parse URL beautifulsoup

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=cars")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
import re
links = soup.findAll("a")
with open('aaa.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")): 
        a = (re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(a)
```

The output of this code is that I have a CSV file where 28 URLs are saved, however the URLs are not correct. For example this is a wrong URL:-

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjg5fahi7nVAhWdHsAKHSQaCekQFgg9MAk&usg=AFQjCNFu_Vg9v1oVhEtR-vKqCJsR2YGd2A

Instead it should be:-

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/

How can I remove the second part for each URL if it contains `"&sa="`

Because then the second part of the URL starting from:-
`"&sa="` should be removed, so that all URLs are saved like the second URL.

I am using python 2.7 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: what you're using re for? what is your purpose of using regex in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every time redundant part of url starts with `&`, you can apply `split()` to each url:

```
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjg5fahi7nVAhWdHsAKHSQaCekQFgg9MAk&usg=AFQjCNFu_Vg9v1oVhEtR-vKqCJsR2YGd2A'
url = url.split('&')[0]
print(url)
```

output:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/
```

Comment: Simple and effective! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way, but you could do one more time split, adding one more line after a:

```
a=[a[0].split("&")[0]]
print(a)
```

Result:

```
['https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_(Film)']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:I2SHYtLktRcJ']
['https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_(Film)%23Handlung']
['https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_(Film)%23Synchronisation']
['https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_(Film)%23Soundtrack']
['https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_(Film)%23Kritik']
['https://www.mytoys.de/disney-cars/']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:9Ohx4TRS8KAJ']
['https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DtNmo09Q3F8s']
['https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DtNmo09Q3F8s']
['https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DkLAnVd5y7M4']
['https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DkLAnVd5y7M4']
['http://cars.disney.com/']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:1BoR6M9fXwcJ']
['http://cars.disney.com/']
['http://cars.disney.com/']
['https://www.whichcar.com.au/car-style/12-cartoon-cars']
['https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D6JSMAbeUS-4']
['http://filme.disney.de/cars-3-evolution']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:fO7ypFFDGk0J']
['http://www.4players.de/4players.php/spielinfonews/Allgemein/36859/2169193/Project_CARS_2-Zehn_Ferraris_erweitern_den_virtuellen_Fuhrpark.html']
['http://www.4players.de/4players.php/spielinfonews/Allgemein/36859/2169193/Project_CARS_2-Zehn_Ferraris_erweitern_den_virtuellen_Fuhrpark.html']
['http://www.play3.de/2017/08/02/project-cars-2-6/']
['http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:-xdXy-yX2fMJ']
['http://www.carmagazine.co.uk/']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:PRPbHf_kD9AJ']
['http://google.com/search%3Ftbm%3Disch%26q%3DCars']
['http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/']
['https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_(Film)']
```

Comment: Simple and effective! Many Thanks!